# Using awk to find the 2nd, 3rd and 4th words in a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, awk

How can I use awk to find the 2nd, 3rd and 4th words out of a string? Say I have a variable named
`line`
and `line="this is a random"`.

I am trying to figure out how to get awk to place "is a random" into a new variable.
I have tried:

```
threewords=$((echo $line | awk '{$2 $3 $4}'))
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.
I need the variable `threewords` to contain the string "is a random".

Comment: try `threewords=$(echo $line | awk '{$2 $3 $4}')`

Comment: i have just tried that, and i just prints empty lines. but at least thats better than just an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `print` command to produce output. Also, put commas between them to get spaces between the words.

And it should be inside `$()`, not `$(())`. The latter is for evaluating arithmetic expressions, not command substitution.

```
threewords=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2, $3, $4}')
```

Comment: this did it! thank you so much its too bad i cannot upvote due to me being a noob. :(